# C# Memory management (Memory leak?)

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, memory-management

I am working on a program in WPF that basically retrieves JSON data from a WEB API and parses it then saves it to database with EF.

The problem is the memory usage of the program keeps on increasing as the time goes by. (From 20MB to 2gigs).

The following is the code that I am using.

Is there any optimization i can perform to keep the memory under a limit and say the unused objects gets deleted periodically.

```
void getMatchInfo_Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        DataConnection dc = new DataConnection();
        dc.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;



       do{
        do
        {
            using (Stream s = client.GetStreamAsync("http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistoryBySequenceNum" +
                "/v1/?key="+devkey+"&start_at_match_seq_num=" + matchseq.ToString()).Result)
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {

                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                MatchMain match;
                MatchDesc player;
                RootElement matchSeq = serializer.Deserialize<RootElement>(reader);
                if (matchSeq.result.status == 1)
                {

                    foreach (var m in matchSeq.result.matches)
                    {


                         match = new MatchMain();
                        match.MatchID = m.match_id;
                        match.Win = m.radiant_win;
                        match.Duration = m.duration;


                        match.StartTime = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(m.start_time);
                        match.TimeStamp = m.start_time;
                        match.SeqNo = m.match_seq_num;
                        matchseq = m.match_seq_num + 1;
                        match.RadTower = m.tower_status_radiant;
                        match.DireTower = m.tower_status_dire;
                        match.RadRax = m.barracks_status_radiant;
                        match.DireRax = m.barracks_status_dire;
                        match.cluster = m.cluster;
                        match.FBTime = m.first_blood_time;
                        match.LobbyType = m.lobby_type;
                        match.HumanCount = m.human_players;
                        match.LeagueID = m.leagueid;
                        match.GameMode = m.game_mode;

                        dc.MatchMain.Add(match);


                        count++;
                        foreach (var p in m.players)
                        {
                             player = new MatchDesc();
                            player.MatchID = m.match_id;
                            player.AccountID = p.account_id;
                            player.PlayerSlot = p.player_slot;
                            player.HeroID = p.hero_id;
                            player.First = p.item_0;
                            player.Second = p.item_1;
                            player.Third = p.item_2;
                            player.Fourth = p.item_3;
                            player.Fifth = p.item_4;
                            player.Sixth = p.item_5;
                            player.Kills = p.kills;
                            player.Deaths = p.deaths;
                            player.Assists = p.assists;
                            player.LeaverStatus = p.leaver_status;
                            player.Gold = p.gold;
                            player.LastHits = p.last_hits;
                            player.Denies = p.denies;
                            player.GPM = p.gold_per_min;
                            player.XPM = p.xp_per_min;
                            player.GoldSpent = p.gold_spent;
                            player.HeroDamage = p.hero_damage;
                            player.TowerDamage = p.tower_damage;
                            player.Healing = p.hero_healing;
                            player.HeroLevel = p.level;

                            dc.MatchDesc.Add(player);



                        }
                        getMatchInfo.ReportProgress(1);
                    }

                    dc.SaveChanges();


                }

                else
                {
                    result = 0;
                }
            }

        } while (result == 1);
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
       }while( result>-999);


    }


void getMatchInfo_Progress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (result != 0)
        {
            txtProgress.Text = count + " matches updated in database and continuing.";

        }
        else
        {
            txtProgress.Text = count + " matches updated in database and waiting for API.";
        }
        txtTime.Text =sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString()+" hours "+ sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString()+" minutes "+
            sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString()+" seconds";
    }
```

Edit: Button click code

```
  private void btnRetrieveData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        getMatchInfo.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getMatchInfo_Work);

        getMatchInfo.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(getMatchInfo_Progress);
        getMatchInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        txtProgress.Text = "Process started";
        matchseq = Convert.ToInt64(txtSeqNo.Text);
        devkey = txtKey.Text;
        sw.Start();
        getMatchInfo.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Comment: So how do you know that the leak is somewhere inside the code you posted?

Comment: because it is the only piece of code getting executed. Basically a Background worker which responds to a button click. Edit: Added the code for button click too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataConnection context keeps tracking all objects that it ever saw. Put creation of dc inside the loop and dispose it every time. You don't need the context after each SaveChanges is called.

Comment: That might temporarily cause increased memory use, but I don't see how that would explain permanent and growing memory consumption.

Comment: Memory grows with every iteration because every object passed to dc.MatchMain.Add(match); and dc.MatchDesc.Add(player); remains in memory eternally. Have you tried to put dc inside the loop and to dispose it?

Comment: Yes it seems to have kept the memory usage to a steady 35-50 mb. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @sysexpand - but every time the getMatchInfo_Work method exits, the DataConnection will go out of scope, and should be GC'ed. Which fixed the problem, changing the scope of the DataConnection, or adding the Dispose?

Comment: There is an outer do { ... } while( result>-999); loop which, I suppose, runs forever. That means that getMatchInfo_Work never returns and therefore data context never goes out of scope. If function ever returned, the memory would be reclaimed by garbage collector (although disposing remains best practice for disposable object).

Comment: @hatchet i just change the scope of DataConnection to after the if statement in the second do-while loop. And yes it's a forever(about 10 days to index all the data) running loop so that's why the Dataconnection object never went out of scope and hence the Growing memory consumption.